# How to pass array arguments and something else?

Tags: windows, powershell, invoke-command

```
$cmd = {
    param([System.Array]$filestocopy = $(throw "need files"),
    [bool]$copyxml)
    if($copy)
        #do stuff
}
$files = @("one","two","three")

invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock $cmd -argumentlist (,$files) $copyxml
```

Error:

> Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.

I have searched high and low and cannot find how to pass in an array along with something in a argumentlist. I have tried: `(,$files,$copyxml)`, `(,$files),$copyxml`, and `(,$files) $copyxml`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to the parameter `-ArgumentList` must be an array, otherwise `$copyxml` will be interpreted as the next positional parameter to `Invoke-Command`. Also, passing the array in a subexpression (`(,$files)`) will cause it to be mangled. Simply passing the variable (`$files`) is sufficient. Change this:

```
invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock $cmd -argumentlist (,$files) $copyxml
```

into this:

```
invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock $cmd -argumentlist $files,$copyxml
```

Comment: Since `$files` is already an array you shouldn't need the `(,$files),$copyxml` and should be able to just do `$files,$copyxml`

Comment: So now when I do a foreach($f in $filestocopy), $f = "fileone filetwo filethree". What happened?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You're right. `(,$files)` doesn't do what the OP wants, because the subexpression mangles the array before passing it into the function.

Comment: I thought I had tried `$files,$copyxml` once, but I guess I didn't. That worked, as expected.